# When coding java in Vim how can i show outout of code directly in in vim when editing

Tags: java, linux, vim, vim-plugin

When editing a Java code in Vim assume I like to see the output of the code. normally I save and come to prompt and compile and run the code.

Is there any way, when editing the code I can see the output of the code in the vim itself?

Vim automatically saves and shows the output without exiting or typing many commands ?

Comment: `:!/bin/bash` Then execute your program. When done `ctrl-d` to return to vim. vim is not an ide.

Comment: Alternately open a second shell in another window and keep it just for executing the program.  Using multiple windows this way can let you look at the program, a debugger and several source files in a way that isn't too different from a simple IDE.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating a mapping, to save the file, compile and run with javac/java. When you want to test your codes, you press the shortcut.

What you described in your question, "showing the output as you editing(typing)", You can do it, vim has`TextChanged` and `TextChangedI` events, you can do something when the events are triggered. However, you won't want it. Because, before your codes become compile-ready, every time you type a key, you will see a compilation error.

Even intellij doesn't support a feature of auto-run a java file as you are editing it.